# How to add items to a list of lists

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I aim to print a list of lists containing entry and exit times in the 24 hour decimal format from the "AM"-"PM" String format input by the user as a String array like this: 
{6AM#8AM, 11AM#1PM, 7AM#8PM, 7AM#8AM, 10AM#12PM, 12PM#4PM, 1PM#4PM, 8AM#9AM}

I declared the individual lists inside the for loop and assigned them values inside the loop but got the following run time exception from my code: 
*java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0*

Kindly help me debug my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TimeSchedule
{  
  public static List<List<Integer>> Timein24hourFormat(String[] input1)
  {
    List<List<Integer>> scheduledTime = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    int [] exitTime = new int[input1.length];
    int [] entryTime = new int[input1.length];
    for (int i=0;i<input1.length;i++)
    { 
      List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
      List<Integer> tempList = scheduledTime.get(i);
      String[] timeSlot = input1[i].split("#");
      for (int m=0;m<2;m++)
      {
        listOfStrings.add(timeSlot[m]);
        if (listOfStrings.contains("AM"))
        { 
          listOfStrings.remove("AM");
          tempList.add(Integer.parseInt(listOfStrings.get(m)));
        }
        if (listOfStrings.contains("PM") && timeSlot[m].contains("12"))
        {
          listOfStrings.remove("PM");
          tempList.add(Integer.parseInt(listOfStrings.get(m)));
        }
        if (listOfStrings.contains("PM") && !timeSlot[m].contains("12"))
        {
          listOfStrings.remove("PM");
          tempList.add((Integer.parseInt(listOfStrings.get(m))) + 12);
        }
      }
     }
    return scheduledTime;
   }

  public static void main (String[]args)
  { 
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int customersNumber = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    String [] entryExitTime = new String[customersNumber];
    for (int i=0;i<customersNumber;i++)
    {
      entryExitTime[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println(Timein24hourFormat(entryExitTime));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Creating a `List<List<Integer>>` does not instantiate any inner `List<Integer>`s. You'll need to add `new List<Integer>` to your outer list based on `input1.length`.

Comment: `for (int j=0;j<input1.length;j++)
    {
      scheduledTime.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
    }`

Comment: I tried adding the above line after the declaration of scheduledTime. This continues to throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<List<Integer>> Timein24hourFormat(String[] input1)
  {
    List<List<Integer>> scheduledTime = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    int [] exitTime = new int[input1.length];
    int [] entryTime = new int[input1.length];
    for (int i=0;i<input1.length;i++)
  { 
    List<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> tempList = scheduledTime.get(i);
    String[] timeSlot = input1[i].split("#");
```

**scheduledTime** is empty at this stage and that's why you can not retrieve value and you get *IndexOutOfBoundsException*

Comment: `for (int j=0;j<input1.length;j++) { scheduledTime.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); }`

Comment: I added the above line after declaring `scheduledTime`. How to assign values to tempList now?

Comment: Could you tell me what is your expected result?  Actually the code is unreadable and written in a bad way.

Comment: Sorry for the bad format of my code. I got rid of the exception but have trouble in removing the "AM" and "PM" from the `listOfStrings`. Can you suggest suitable in-built methods for this?

Comment: Conditions in your code are never met because your list contains the value like "7AM" not the "AM". So the following line and the next one are not good for this case.

    if (listOfStrings.contains("AM"))

Comment: I mean to say that is there any in-built method for checking parts of a String.For instance,  `if (listOfStrings.contains("AM"))`. This fails to check the value "3AM". I wish to checkif the value has "AM" in it or not.

Comment: Or Perhaps, alternative datastructures to achieve this?

Comment: for(String s: listOfStrings){
                    if(s.contains("AM")){
                        //to do sth
                    }
                }

Comment: I used substring() to store the integer and "AM-PM" part of each string in separate strings and then carried out the conditional check.